# Execute .done() function some times

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I need your help for a little problem. I have this code

```
if (hash == "#favorites") { // Favorites
    fill_favorites();
}

function getdata() {
    return $.ajax({
       url:"http://domain.com/assets/mobile/getmyfavorites.php?userid="+window.user_id,
       dataType: 'json',
       success:function(data){
            if(!data) {
                return [];
            } else {
                return data;
            }
       }
    });
}


function fill_favorites() {
        getdata().done(function(result) {
            var data = result;
            favorites.empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var obj = data[i];
                var elem = $("<div class='my show favorite'><img src='"+obj.url+"'/><div>"+obj.title+"</div>");
                favorites.append(elem);
            }
        });
}
function add_favorite(url, title) {
    getdata().done(function(result){
        var data = result;
        console.log(data);
        data.push({"title":title, "url":url});
        window.favoritesimages.push(url);
        var posting = $.post( set_userfavorites, { Images: window.favoritesimages, UserID: window.user_id } );
        posting.done(function(data){
            console.log("success");
            fill_favorites();
        });

    });
}
```

that will fetch my favorites from the database and then do the print on the screen. My problem is in updating favorites, whenever I add a new favorite, the favorites do not update soon, it takes a while to update again. Can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean by it takes a while to update again.? Can you please elaborate.

Comment: If you have problem with update part, show us the update code.

Comment: When do you call `fill_favorites`? Note that the `success` callback does not do anything. The return value disappears into oblivion.

Comment: @GeekAb I mean that whenever I add a new favorite and enter the bookmarks it is not there, however in the database updates.

Comment: @trincot I have now updated the code with the part I call fill_favorites.

Comment: So, it appear after some time? For example after 5 seconds or more

Comment: @GeekAb No, I update the page after about 10 minutes already appears. I think it's because it runs .done () once and never runs again.

Comment: You have absolutly no error handling: are you sure all the requests are successful? Add .fail(...) after each .done(...) to check.

Comment: The code you have shown is only 3 functions, therefore it will not run even once. Show the code you are using to actually call the functions...

Comment: @Milney I've already updated my code. The idea is when the user logs in to fetch the bookmarks from the database. And each time you add a new bookmark, it updates its page.

Comment: in add_favourite, why do you call getdata() first? It already gets called at the end (as a result of calling fill_favourites() after you've posted your data)? Seems like a waste of time, because at that point the data is unchanged. And I agree with others, you have no error handling. You won't know if your calls are failing or timing out or something. At the very least check your browser console / network view to see if there are any problems when you get one that doesn't update. But preferably add error handling so your users know what has happened and your code can deal with it.

Comment: Thanks to all but the problem after all was server cache :(